# Role and permission custom Model

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a custom Model of Autorization that i want to represent with spring security :

I have the concpt of roles and permissions :

```
@Entity
public class User
...............
@ManyToMany
@Column
private Set<Role> roles;


@ManyToMany
@Column
private Set<Permission> permissions;
  }
```

In my custom UserdetailsService i have a clean way to load the roles but i on't find any way and any componenent in spring-security related to the permissions :

```
public class BELUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
 User connectedUser = userRepositoy.findUserByUsername(username);

     Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
    for (Role r :connectedUser.getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getRoleAWB().name()));
    }


    BELUserDetails belUserDetails = new BELUserDetails(connectedUser.getIdUser(), authorities);
.....
....
    }
```

}

My roles are :

ADMIN
NORMAL USER 
TRANSACTION USER

My Permissions are : 
VALIDATE_TRANSATION 
INIT_TRANSACTION

And the functional use case is if you want Validate a Transaction you have to have the ROLE TRANSACTION USER and the permission VALIDATE_TRANSACTION.

```
hasRole("ROLE_TRANSACTION_USER") and hasPermission("VALIDATE_TRANSACTION")
```

Another important case is that i want in the future use PermissionEvaluator to put some limits when trying to validate a transaction if the user has the Role "ROLE_TRANSACTION_USER" and the permission VALIDATE_TRANSACTION , he must also have a Amountlimit greater than the amount of the transaction and this functionality is very cool with PermissionEvaluator

That's why i need to implements both Role and permission Concepts

How i will add my permission to the standard flow of spring-security .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you show some examples for permissions?

Comment: I update the post with some examples of my Roles and Permissions

Comment: Another case is that i want in the future use PermissionEvaluator to put some limits when trying to validate a transaction if the user has the Role "ROLE_TRANSACTION_USER" and the permission VALIDATE_TRANSACTION , he must also have a Amountlimit greater than the amount of the transaction and this functionality is very cool with PermissionEvaluator .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you have only authorities in Spring Security. Just add all your roles and permissions into authorities collection. Then you can do:

```
hasRole("ROLE_TRANSACTION_USER") and hasRole("VALIDATE_TRANSACTION")
```

In most cases mixing the two is not a problem.

You have permissions in [Spring Security ACL module](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls), but you need ACL only if you want to have different security rules per domain object.

**EDIT.** I think the most easy way to do some additional security checks is to use SpEL. Example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_TRANSACTION_USER') 
     and hasRole('VALIDATE_TRANSACTION') 
     and @amountValidatorServiceBean.isAmountValidForCurrentUser(#amount)")
public void doTransaction(Integer amount, ...)
```

Comment: The problem with considering VALIDATE_TRANSACTION as a Role is that we will not be able to use a custom PermissionEvaluator to test if the user has the right to validate a transaction with a given amount .

Comment: It may be more easy to call some validation logic directly in annotation using SpEL. See details in my answer.

Comment: Thanks i will implement with this solution